# Using meteor's websocket for webRTC Signalling

Tags: meteor, webrtc

I am currently working on a web app where I need real time interaction between different people. I am using WebRTC powered by [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/) to add real time interactivity to my app. 
Now I have started experimenting with Meteor and I'm impressed by it's real time capabilities.

When I'm trying to use PeerJS with Meteor it is throwing this error:

```
Users/sauravpanda/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object../adapter (app/dist/peer.js:279:1)
    at s (app/dist/peer.js:1:385)
    at e (app/dist/peer.js:1:556)
    at app/dist/peer.js:1:574
    at app/dist/peer.js:2941:3
    at /Users/sauravpanda/Desktop/aswus/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/sauravpanda/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /Users/sauravpanda/Desktop/aswus/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
Exited with code: 8
```

How can I fix this and use WebRTC with Meteor?

I am thinking of writing my own WebRTC signalling server using socket.io and I wish to use meteor's native WebSocket support to be used for the client. According to my limited understanding of Meteor, it is already supporting in someways what `RTCDatachannel` is doing. So the only thing I need to add is support for `RTCPeerConnection` and `getUserMedia`.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to place peer.js in the `clients/` folder of your meteor app, otherwise it will try to execute it both on the client and server side, while `window` exists only in the browser.